# implicit conversion between 'void' and '<null>'?

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-operator

I am trying to do a very simple thing here -

I need to find a control in a table layout panel

1) if the control exists - Delete the control

2) else i don't need to do anything

I decided to use conditional operator for it besides of if\else condition. My code for this is:

```
var temp=(tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0].Name==("lbl3")) ? (tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0].Dispose()) : null ;
```

but i am facing this error :

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'void' and '<null>'
```

there are so many solutions on google but none of them is working for me and i didn't found any solution for null and void, stucked in it, need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to not use the `var` keyword, as the compiler can't infer the type from the two parts.

Comment: @SteveB: That's not the issue here.

Comment: Yes, I understood this later. I also upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dispose` doesn't return anything, it has a return value of `void`. `void` can't be assigned to a variable.

Using a conditional operator in your scenario really makes no sense at all. Simply use this:

```
var control = tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0];
if(control.Name==("lbl3"))
    control.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

In a conditional expression using the ternary operator, both sides of the expression should return the same value. In your expression the first side returns void, the second side returns null and the two are not the same thing.

Have you ever seen something like this:

```
 var test = void; // <- doesn't compile
```

I find your use of the conditional operator very confusing and not needed

I think that this is more clear

```
var temp=tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true);
if(temp != null && temp.Length > 0)
   temp[0].Dispose();
```

By the way, the Find method of the ControlsCollection class

> Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of
>   all the controls that match.

So there is no need to check against the name, but a check to see if at least one control has been retrieved is safer

Answer (score 1):

> "I decided to use conditional operator for it"

Don't.

There is no reason to use the conditional operator for this, as you are not looking to get a value. It will only make the code harder to understand, as you are doing the actual work as a side effect of the expression, and getting a nonsense value as result.

The reason for the error that you are getting is that one operand is returning `null` and the other operand is not returning anything at all. To use a conditional operator both operands have to return a value, and the values have to be compatible.

Just use an `if` statement:

```
Control c = tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0];
if (c.Name==("lbl3")) {
  c.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign `null`to `var temp`, see  this page http://www.dotnetperls.com/var. Use any other value instead.
In addition to that make sure your `Dispose`function returns a value unequal to `void` and `null`.

Comment: While true, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to something like this:

```
var temp = (tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0].Name == ("lbl3"))  
       tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0] : null;
if ( temp != null )
    temp.Dispose();
```

For details check:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029 (7.14 Conditional operator)

Answer (score 0):

`void` is not a real data type, it is used to state that a method doesn't return any value. To work around I think you can do something like this:

```
public static class ControlExtension {
     public static object Dispose2(this Control c){
         c.Dispose();
         return null;//or anything you want
     }
}
//Then
var temp=(tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0].Name==("lbl3")) ? (tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Find("lbl3", true)[0].Dispose2()) : null ;
```